# split a column based on the lend of string

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a column with values such as 45672Qty, 45672Cost. I am trying to split into 2 columns :

Val = storing the numbers on the left side of the string
Type = storing the words (cost, qty) on the right hand of the string

There is no delimiter that I can use to split the values

I am quite new to the python world so struggling to find a good solution.

**My latest attempt code to split based on length of the string:**

```py
df_mrp_unp['ln'] = df_mrp_unp['TP'].str.len()

df_mrp_unp['dt_part'] = df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[:5]

df_mrp_unp['Val_Type'] = df_mrp_unp['TP'].apply(lambda x: df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[-3:] if df_mrp_unp['ln'] = 8 else  df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[-4:]  )
```

but I getting the following error which I don't understand why.

```
  File "<ipython-input-71-f01490fc581a>", line 7
    df_mrp_unp['Val_Type'] = df_mrp_unp['TP'].apply(lambda x: df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[-3:] if df_mrp_unp['ln'] = 8 else  df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[-4:]  )
                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `np.where`

```
df_mrp_unp['Val_Type'] = np.where(df_mrp_unp['ln'] == 8,
                                  df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[-3:],
                                  df_mrp_unp['TP'].str[-4:])
```